# Sound Editors dilemma

Tags: career-advice

I have been working (moonlighting) as a Sound Editor in NYC for 2 years now.  (Foley, DX, FX and MX) I am working a day job and have been pretty lucky in that I can edit at night/weekends.

However, I am beginning to feel like this is never going to grow into a full time gig.  As I find directors and producers to work for, I find myself as the only person on the post sound crew (no mentorship/learning from others at all).

This makes me think that I should just be working for Supervising Sound Editors and not Producers and Directors directly.

Can anyone provide any insight into taking this next step from part time to full time?

Comment: @Chris Davis, there's much to be said on this topic. I recommend you read through some of the previous threads on similar topics for insight: 
http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/5532/moving-worlds-within-audio-post
http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/2050/whats-the-best-city-for-sound-designers-to-start-their-careers

Answer (score 2):

What research have you done in terms of finding a supervising sound editor to approach? Its not hard these days to find out who is doing all the work, I'd start a big list of all the NY Supervising sound editors & even try & track who their teams are (its usually all listed on IMDB) then you'll have some insight into who is busiest... But remember if a team has just started a project it was probably crewed six months ago - they need to know you, your work & your work ethics, approach, personality & availability before a project ever comes to them....

Comment: +1 Indeed, it is a highly-selective process.  Good idea on approach - IMDB does have all the info especially of you dig deep enuogh and compare/contrast names that keep popping up on different shows.  Sometimes you can begin to see patterns of working relationships between sound editors and between directors/producers and their sound crews.  Just takes a little bit of digital pavement-pounding

Comment: I have basically been doing what you've said.  IMDB research.  My biggest problem however, is my schedule. I work a day job.  I don't know that other folks would really want to hire someone that can't work during the day.  

I am aware that EVERYONE has this problem at first, but I honestly don't see a way out of the day job without freelance work (enough of it).  Which is , again, tough to do while working a day job.    

Answer (score 1):

After you find the folks on IMDB, I would also check out any Linkedin profiles...they may know someone you know. It is always better to be introduced than to cold call. It is a small world.

Comment: +1 I've had much better luck when contacting someone i really want to work with when i've been able to say "(mutual contact) recommended that i get in touch with you"